# Evaluating $\int^1_0 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{x} \log(1+x)\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, polylogarithm

How would you solve the following?

$$\int^1_0 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{x} \log(1+x)\, \mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\int \frac{\log(1+x)}{x} \, \mathrm dx=-\text{Li}_2(-x)$$

**Added later**

Using the trick given in the hint, then $$\int \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{x} \log(1+x)\, \mathrm dx=-\frac{\text{Li}_2(-x){}^2}{2}$$ and so $$\int^1_0 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{x} \log(1+x)\, \mathrm dx=-\frac{\pi ^4}{288}$$

Comment: very nice hint there!

Comment: @Chinny84. Thanks ! It is a so complex integral (at first glance) that there must be a trick !

Comment: No problem. I am committing all these nice tricks to my mathematical "toolbox"! So Thank you.

Comment: @Chinny84. I really would enjoy to have a tour in your toolbox ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Send me an email if you want to discuss anything offline. I will update my profile accordingly :). Keep well.

Comment: I wish a numerical value of this integral.Tank

Comment: I updated my answer